# Does each Visual Studio version need its own cloned git repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I've been successfully using Git on VisualStudio.com through the Team Explorer of VS2013. I just installed the VS2015 preview and, when I connected to my VisualStudio.com space, it said I need to close the repositories before I can do anything. The Default Repository Location setting is the same for both VS versions and the repos are definitely already there. If I try to clone, it will prompt me to create a 2nd repo ("Source\Repos\MyProject2").

Shouldn't VS2015 use the same local git repository as VS2103?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can <kbd>add</kbd> them by adding them to Visual Studio, then they will show up.

[image]

To remove one, it's going to be just as obvious, hit <kbd>del</kbd> or use the context menu:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I'm oblivious. Thanks!

Comment: Another question : how to remove the local git repository ?